# Dropped Item in hot water heater

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, appliances, hot-water

When I was redoing the plumbing to my hot water heater I accidentally dropped a pen cap down the vent stack/flu.

Will this cause any problems? Like melting or catching on fire?

Its going to take a good bit of time to unhook the gas line and empty the tank to be able to tip it so I can remove the flue baffle, because of where it is currently located.

I'd rather not spend all that time if its a nonissue. My hunch is that it could be.

thanks for your help,

rookie

Answer (score 5):

Since you have a flue I assume it is either gas/propane or oil fired. Most water heaters have cover near the base to service the burner or the igniter. First shut off the fuel source.  If you remove the cover you should be able to look inside with the aid of a flashlight. Most burners are round and you may find that the cap has fallen into the center and may even be on the floor under the tank.

Comment: @kyle petricek, it is customary and proper to award a correct answer by accepting it. How about hooking up @mikes?